# How to use resources defined in <Styles.Resources> inside Resource Dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

I have a resource dictionary which is a datagrid style defined on it and a style inside that datagrid style.

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGrid}" x:Key="CatalogDataGrid">
    <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}" x:Key="RightAlignedDataGridCell">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
                        <Border
                            Padding="5,0"
                            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                            <ContentPresenter
                            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Then in my XAML I tried to use `RightAlignedDataGridCell` so that my column be right aligned.

```
<DataGrid... Style="{StaticResource CatalogDataGrid}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Total" Binding="{Binding Total}"
                            CellStyle="{StaticResource RightAlignedDataGridCell}">
        </DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

When I run my app I received resource not found exception. If I put that style on resource dictionary root. It could work. But I want `RightAlignedDataGridCell` stays inside
`<Style.Resources>` of `CatalogDataGrid`.

**How to use that `RightAlignedDataGridCell` on my XAML without moving it to resource dictionary root?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to include the resourcedictionary in the resource section of whatever control/window etc you are using for it to be found. You can do this via [MergedDictionaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx).

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="myresourcedictionary.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

Comment: x:Key="RightAlignedDataGridCell". You need to remove this I think.

Comment: Can't do.. because the column will be left aligned.

Comment: Aaah. Sorry. I didn't read your question correctly. Starting over: Why do you not want it in resourcedictionary root? I see no logical reason.

Comment: The answer to your question is that if you define a resource within an element's resources section you can only use it within the element. If you define it within a style you can use it within a style. If you want to use it outside define it outside. What you want to do it not possible and more importantly serves no purpose.

Comment: I have 3 datagrid styles, each datagrid have 3 aligned cell styles (left, center, right). Each cell style has different color background. I just want to encapsulate those styles into related datagrid. So that cell style names would be the same for those datagrids.

Thanks @NVM for pointing it. I guess i overcomplicate things.

I ends up using style's Trigger and Tag on datagrid style to achieve what i want.